# Custom form validation

Tags: forms, errors

I have created a basic form which can be POST to `admin-post.php` and also submitted via an AJAX call to `admin-ajax.php`. Both submissions work correctly, use the `nonce` for a little extra security, and I can process the data as required.

My question and problem is how, with the regular form POST to `admin-post.php`, to send back a message to the form with either a success message string, or an error - which could be a string, or an array of invalid form field entries? With the AJAX call I can simply echo a json encoded response.

I know there is no session set unless I manually call `session_start()` and also using globals isn't ideal. Is there some other sort of storage or system I can use to pass these messages?

I've used [transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) before - would these be suitable? I understand the transient data may not be available at any given moment so perhaps not?

Could I use the [WP_Error](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd use a JSON response containing an `error` property.

```
<?php
echo json_encode( [
    'error' => [
        'code'    => 'my_error_code',
        'message' => 'My error message.',
        'data'    => [any additional data you need],
    ],
] );
```

Your AJAX callback should look for the `error` and adapt accordingly.

---

For the regular POST, you'd want to generate HTML markup that produces a [WP Notice](https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/), or that produces markup that you will style as a notice. See: [Complete Guide to Notices](https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but I have already done the AJAX method, I just need a way to display a message (error / or success) for the `admin-post.php` call. Admin notices can't be used on the front-end can they?